# Windows 10 - Remote desktop on "ghost" screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, remote-control

I have the following problematic:

At work, I have a laptop with 3 monitors. Sometimes, I take my laptop at home to work.

At home, I have a private computer with 3 screens, but I need to work on my work's laptop. I can work on the single little screen of the laptop, or unplug all screens from my private computer and connect them to my work laptop, but both are uncomfortable.

I would like to use my private computer to connect in remote desktop to my work laptop and use my 3 screens. The programs that I tried to connect in remote desktop supports multiple screens, but these screens have to be physically connected to the remote computer.

My question is: how can I add 2 or more "ghost" monitors to my work laptop to be able to use TeamViewer or Windows Remote Desktop on 3 monitors or do you know a remote control program that can do that?

Comment: Team Viewer can't do this, but Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection can. There's an option in the connection settings, something like *Use all of my monitors*. Enable that before connecting to the remote computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Twisty Impersonator:

> Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection can. There's an option in the connection settings, something like Use all of my monitors.

This option does exactly what I want to do. Thanks